# How To Disconnect DVD-ROM From Laptop?

Tags: dvd, optical-drive, hp-pavilion, connection

I have HP Pavilion dv5282ea and after sending it to laboratory, i noticed that my DVD-ROM activates from time to time, just like i am opening and closing it. I know i should open my laptop and fix the thing, but i am not confident in my technical laptop skills at this time and affraid to mess with laptop since it has sensitive information.

Is there a way to disconnect DVD-ROM drive without opening laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, removing the optical drive from a laptop does not require actually opening the laptop case itself.  Most often, you'll just need to remove one or two screws which are accessible from the exterior.  Then, the drive will either come out with a simple pull, or there will be an ejection mechanism to press.

Many large OEMs have service manuals available on their websites.  If the removal process isn't obvious to you from just looking at the laptop, I suggest checking there.  I tried looking on HP's website myself, but they do not have anything on a "Pavillion dv5282".  Before doing your own search, make sure you got the model number right or try using the auto-detect feature.

Another option, if you just want to leave it in, is to disable it in the OS.

For Windows:

- Run "devmgmt.msc" from the Start Menu, Run dialog, or command line.
- Locate your device in the tree, right-click and select "Disable".

Comment: No, disabling in OS does not help.